# bulk edit xml document library sharepoint 2010

Tags: xml, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am an enduser of a SharePoint 2010 Document Library
which has inventory items saved as xml files in Sharepoint 2010 document library.

I've tried few things but am not able to update the XMLs in bulk.

I am able to import it in Excel but not able to export to XMLs. A workaround could be replacing these new XMLs to the library.

Any leads?

Comment: What kind of update you are looking for ?

Comment: updating XML fields as in Excel sheet. 
I can view the XML contents in Datasheet view but it is Read Only

Comment: You could open the library in explorer view and edit from there

Comment: that will be one-by-one. I wish to edit it in bulk as in Excelsheet view. How bout workaround via SQL Server? am currently trying to do the following: 1. import Excelsheet into a table, 2. create XML schema, 3. write T-SQL to export to different XMLs. Any leads on this? However, I wish to lessen code/programming dependency to achieve this task

Comment: btw am not able to open the library in explorer view currently; its throwing some compatibility error today but i was able to open the view till last week